# El stream de conexion bosh no continua, con Strophe y Ejabberd

Tags: xml, xmpp, ejabberd

```
var Iniciar = {
    user: 'user1@im.server.com',
    pass: 'user1',
    conexion: null,...
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Iniciar.log('Iniciando conexion');
    $(document).trigger('conectar');
});

$(document).bind('conectar', function () {
    //conexion
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://192.168.0.1:5280/bosh');
    Iniciar.conexion = conn;
    Iniciar.conexion.rawInput = Iniciar.raw_entrada;
    Iniciar.conexion.rawOutput = Iniciar.raw_salida;
    Iniciar.conexion.addHandler(Iniciar.on_presence, null, "presence");

    Iniciar.conexion.connect(
                    Iniciar.user, 
                    Iniciar.pass,
                    function(status){
                        if(status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING){ ...else if(status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED){
                        $('#cuadro').append(' 2 de 3 conectado ');
                        $(document).trigger('conectando');
                    }else{
                        //
                    }
                }
);
```

El codigo anterior me permite ingresar una sola vez, luego cierro seccion. Para posterior ingresar nuevamente pero no ingresa y en el log me despliega el mesaje.
y asi sucesivamente tengo que reiniciar el servidor para ingresar una vez...
Estoy Utilizando Ejabberd 18.06 on windows server2008 he congiurado en IIS
y el servidor esta instalado en una red local.

> Resp.C  http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='im.server.com'
>   xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8'
>   ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
>       Resp.S  http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'
>   xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmpp:version='1.0'
>   authid='5304187563466404975'
>   sid='3c410c892727785a65ed19e27de577ea04c5c5d1' wait='60' ver='1.11'
>   polling='2' inactivity='30' hold='1' xmpp:restartlogic='true'
>   requests='2' secure='true' maxpause='120' from='im.server.com'/>

```
Conexion Fallida!
```